# How to BREAK the loops in Selenium Robot framework 3.2.2 - Getting an error 'Break' is a reserved keyword

Tags: python, java, selenium, robotframework

How can I break the **Get data count** and **Get row count** FOR loops, once my IF condition is satisfy.

Here I want to select a date through for loop, but currently my if condition is satisfied still its continue executing the for loop.

```
Library    SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${browserName}    chrome
${siteURL}    https://www.booking.com/

*** Test Cases ***
Login should failed with unregistered email
    Open website login page
    Click login
    Get row count
    #[Teardown]    Close Browser

*** Keywords ***
Open website login page
    Open Browser    ${siteURL}    ${browserName}
    Maximize Browser Window
    
Click login
    Click Element    //div[@class='xp__dates-inner']//span[@class='sb-date-field__icon sb-date-field__icon-btn bk-svg-wrapper calendar-restructure-sb']
    Wait Until Page Contains Element    //div[@class='xp__dates-inner']//span[@class='sb-date-field__icon sb-date-field__icon-btn bk-svg-wrapper calendar-restructure-sb']
    
Get row count
    ${rowTRCount}=  Get Element Count    //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr
    FOR  ${indexTR}    IN RANGE   1    ${rowTRCount}+1  
        ${curTRText}      Get Text      //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[${indexTR}]
        Log To Console    TR: ${curTRText}
        Get data count    ${indexTR} 
    END
    
Get data count   
    [Arguments]    ${indexTR}
    Log To Console   ${indexTR}
    Set Test Variable    ${conditionCheck}    ${False}
    Convert To Boolean    ${conditionCheck}  
    ${rowTDCount}=  Get Element Count    //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[${indexTR}]/td
    FOR  ${indexTD}    IN RANGE   1   ${rowTDCount}+1
        ${noDate}    Get Text    //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[${indexTR}]/td[${indexTD}]
        Exit For Loop IF    '${noDate}' == ''
        ${curTDText}      Get Text      //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[${indexTR}]/td[${indexTD}]//span
        Log To Console    TD: ${curTDText}
        ${CurrentDate}=      Get Time    day
        ${dayConvertToInt}=    Convert To Integer    ${CurrentDate}  
        ${finalDate}=    Evaluate   ${dayConvertToInt}+ 10
        Run Keyword If    ${curTDText}==${finalDate}    Select date    ${indexTR}    ${indexTD}    ${conditionCheck}
    END
    
Select date
    [Arguments]    ${indexTR}    ${indexTD}    ${conditionCheck}
    Click Element    //*[@id="frm"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[${indexTR}]/td[${indexTD}]//span
    BREAK
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Exit For Loop" in the place of "Pass Execution", because pass execution "Skips rest of the current test, setup, or teardown with PASS status."

"Exit For Loop" only exits the for loop and continues the next keywords in test case
For you, "Exit For Loop" would be the right choice for you as per your question.

```
Exit For Loop
```

Detailed documentation of pass execution:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Pass%20Execution

Comment: as per "Exit For Loop" Its only break one loop, and here I want to break all the for loops (Get data count and Get row count), While using "Exit For Loop" will break only (Get data count) for loop, not even break (Get row count).

Comment: but yes agree with you its skipped all the next keyword statements, So do you have any idea how can I solve my problem ?